# Getting Data out of Firebase Object with Angular2, angularfire2 and Typescript

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

Im currently working on a Project with Angular 2 and angularFire2.
My database looks like this in Firebase:
base:/data

```
[{Name:test1},
{Name:test2},
{Name:test3}]
```

All of the items also have the Firebase key.

Now im trying to get data out of the Firebase with the Observabels from RX.
When i do this, i get the names in the Console:

```
let items= af.database.list('/data').map(i=>{return i});
items.forEach(i=>i.forEach(e=>(console.log(e.name))));
```

Output: test1,test2,test3. Everything Works.

But when i do this:

```
console.log(items.first());
```

I get a FirebaseListObservable back.

How can i get only the First Object from the FirebaseListObservable? 
How can i edit Items in the list? like:

```
items[0].name=test3
```

And How can i get the Firebase Key from an Item

how can i get The firebaseKey from an Item in the list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Observables` are an asynchronous data structure, meaning that you don't actually know when the data is going to be available, you have to subscribe to the `Observable` and wait for the data to become available in the `next` handler.

```
items.first().subscribe(x => console.log(x.name));
```

Further, an `Observable` is not static, so you can't index into it as such. If you need only the first item then I would suggest instead that you extract the value and modify it with a `flatMap` + `first` + `map` combination.

```
af.database.list('/data')
  //Convert array into Observable and flatten it
  .flatMap(list => list)
  //Get only the first item in this list
  .first()
  //Transform the value
  .map(({name, firebaseKey}) => ({name: "test3", firebaseKey}))
  //Subscribe to the stream
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: THANK you, that really helped me.

Comment: What if you wanted to loop over the items, rather than just the first?

Comment: @Lloyd then you would use `flatMap` instead of `first`

Comment: You have flatMap in there.  So just take first() out?

Comment: Yes just remove the `first` in that case

Comment: I used `af.list('/data').subscribe(x => console.log(x));` And I got all the data loaded to the app component.